# Poisson distribution excercise, finding $\lambda$

Tags: probability

On a motorway, in a 5 minute interval it is equally likely whether a car exceeds the speed limit or not. 
What is the probability that exactly 3 car exceed the speed limit in this 5 minute?

I need to calculate $\lambda$. I did $\lambda=0.5*1+0.5*0=0.5$

Is that correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is $\lambda$? i think you need to somehow connect the poisson distribution to the problem.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the average number of cars that exceed the speed limit in $5$ minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Let us have $n$ cars on the motorway, each having probability $\pi\in[0,1]$ to exceed the speed limit. The probability that exactly 3 cars will exceed the limit is then according to binomial distribution
$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\3\end{array}\right)\pi^3(1-\pi)^{n-3}$.